# Can an object contain its superclass?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, uml

For example (in Java, but the question is about every oo language):

```
    public class A { public int i;}

    public class B extends A { 
       private A a;
       B(A aa) { a = aa;}
    }

    public class C {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           A a1 = new A();
           B b1 = new B(a1);
           B b2 = new B(b1);
       }
   }
```

As I see, it is working in Java, but I don't know it is really allowed or should be avoided. I need it for UML making, not for concrete code.

Comment: Yes it can. Whether it is a good idea or not depends on what you're actually doing.

Comment: For instance, `FilterInputStream`, which extends `InputStream`, has a field referencing another `InputStream`.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be allowed and accepted.  Sometimes there's _no avoiding_ it.  Consider, for example, an `IfStatement` object that must both _inherit from_ `Statement` and _contain_ two `Statement` objects.

Comment: hmmm, `Object` is the superclass of almost everything... not always direct, but still.... would be *boring* if subclasses of it were not allowed to have fields with other Objects... just thinking

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can do that:

[image]

`SubClass` (B) is a `SuperClass` (A) and it also holds an owned property `general` (a; though it's public in my example) of type `SuperClass`.